# tab bar layout issue swift storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

So I have tab bar that I have implemented with a blur effect as shown in img (1). It works perfectly in all my views, except one. In my profileView, I have added a scroll view and applied all the necessary constraints as shown in img (2), but the blurred effect is no longer visible as shown in img (3). I have no idea why adding a scroll view adds this extra layer in my hierarchy, and removing the scroll view entirely does fix the issue, so I am really lost as to what is the source of the issue. Weirdly, even in storyboard, when there is a scrollView embedded in a nav bar with the tab as the root controller, a black bar appears at the bottom of the screen as shown in img (4). Another thing to note is that when I scroll to the bottom of the view, the tab bar looks as expected as shown in img (5).

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmKnv.jpg)
[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9uvB.png)

[img 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckYZL.jpg)
[img 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0EJz.png)

[img 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFog1.jpg)

[tab bar controller scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjTrb.png)

[hierarchy with incorrect layout of tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU5nK.png)
[hierarchy with correct layout of tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akZJ6.png)

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpTabBar()
    }

    func setUpTabBar() {
        // Set the custom view as the tab bar's background color
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear

        // Add a gradient layer to the tab bar
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.1).cgColor
        ]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(a: 0.88, b: 0.93, c: -0.93, d: 24.57, tx: 0.58, ty: -12.22))
        gradientLayer.bounds = self.tabBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: -0.5 * self.tabBar.bounds.size.width, dy: -0.5 * self.tabBar.bounds.size.height)
        gradientLayer.position = self.tabBar.center
        self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        // Apply corner radius to the tab bar
        self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

        // Add blur effect to tab bar's layer
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .prominent)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = self.tabBar.bounds
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.tabBar.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)

        // Set the tab bar to be non-translucent
        self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.tabBar.itemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.tabBar.items!.count)
        self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
        self.tabBar.itemSpacing = 0

        // Set selected images for each tab bar item
        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
                item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "selected_icon_\(index)")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            }
        }

        // Remove unwanted UIImageView layers
        for subview in self.tabBar.subviews {
            if subview is UIImageView && subview.bounds.height <= 1 {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the constraints of the scroll view, and nothing changed. I removed all my content inside my scrollView and the result is the same, so I know it is specific to adding the scrollView to my view controller. I have tried to compare the view hierarchies of the view where the tab bar looks correct and another that doesnt to identify any differences that may be causing the issue (img 6&7)

Comment: Is your tab bar a completely custom implementation or are you modifying the appearance of a UITabBarController’s tab bar. The way that the appearance differs depending on whether you scroll to the bottom of your content enough makes me suspect there is a standard toolbar or tab bar in your hierarchy. On iOS 16 (or was it 15?) standard bars are transparent when there is no content behind them. If you select the black view and see it in the hierarchy on the left, what type of view is it and what hierarchy is it in? Your tab bar or something in UIKit?

Comment: I attach a class called TabbarController to my tab bar in storyboard. I added the code for that to my question. I also added a screenshot of my tabController scene for further clarification. Please let me know if you have any other questions. It is just odd how this issue only happens in one controller (with the scroll view) and none of my other controllers.

Comment: I still think the iOS behaviour of making tab bars transparent when there is no content behind them (when using a scroll view) is part of the problem. It seems too much of a coincidence that it works when you scroll to the bottom of your content. You are making lots of changes to the internals of the tab bar, which might be conflicting with the default behaviour.

Comment: You could maybe try to mess around with the different appearances (before making your customisations) to try and bypass the iOS 15/16 behaviour (see https://nemecek.be/blog/126/how-to-disable-automatic-transparent-navbar-in-ios-15). Or maybe if you add an extra full screen view as a parent to your scroll view that might stop iOS from realising there is a scroll view there and it will stop changing appearance?

Comment: how can i add an extra screen view as a parent? I will try looking at the blog and attempt to implement that. But it seems the blog talks about nav bar appearance and not tab bar appearance?

Comment: Tab bar has similar appearance methods. I’m just guessing that this is the problem because it works in other tabs without a scroll view. My idea was to add a view as a parent to the scroll view in the profile tab so that the view controller’s root view isn’t a scroll view. Maybe that is already the case, so this won’t work.

Comment: Another thing to try as an experiment would be to temporarily comment out all the customisation code in the tab bar controller subclass and see how it behaves in the different tabs. This should give you default behaviour and maybe you would see the tab bar going transparent when there is no scroll content underneath it. This might help understand what is happening.